# Not able to spyOn the interleaved success callback of an ajax in Jasmine unit testing

Tags: jquery, jasmine

In source code I have one getJSON call with two success callback in the following structure.

Source code to test:

```
jsonMakeLineOrderData = $.getJSON(url, jsonData,
                                  function (data) {
                                      console.log("Inside 1st callback");   
                                      //… some other statement
                                  }).success(function (data) {      // line# 1
                                            console.log("Inside 2nd callback");
                                            //… some other statement
                                      });
```

I am using Jasmine testing framework to test the success blocks of this call.

To fake/mock the ajax call I have used spyOn utility.

My Jasmine test spec:

```
it ("Test Function",function(){
    var data = <json_data>;
    var d;
    spyOn($, "ajax").andCallFake(function(params) {
        params.success(data);           // line# 2
        d = $.Deferred();
        d.resolve(data);
        return d.always();
    });
});
```

In the above example I am able to test the 1st callback but not able to test the 2nd callback.

The 1st callback is executing due to line# 2 in the test spec.

I have tried to use jQuery deferred instance to execute the 2nd callback but it is throwing *“TypeError: $.getJSON(...).success is not a function”* error, if I change the *.success()* statement to *.done()* in the source file at line # 1 the test case is working fine, but I am not able to make it work with *.success()*, unfortunately I am not suppose to change the source file, so I have to work with *.success()*.

If anybody has any solution please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return a function that will call the callback like this:

```
it ("Test Function",function(){
    var data = <json_data>;
    spyOn($, "getJSON").andReturn({success: function(c){c(data)}});
});
```

For easier ajax testing I would advice [sinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/) which has a simple way to mock the ajax with a [fake server](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer).

Comment: I have used the same syntax as you proposed

Comment: Thank you Andreas for the response.
I have used the same syntax as you have proposed with the actual data as below.
    spyOn($, "getJSON").return({success: function(c){c(testData)}});
But getting the following error 
_italic_ TypeError: spyOn(...).return is not a function
I might be doing some mistake, but I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

Comment: My fault its `andReturn` not just `return`, updated my answer.

Comment: @ Andreas, Now I am facing some related issue in a little extended manner. In my source code I have called jqXHR.success() method from some other javascript function, now I want to test the success block of this 3rd callback using Jasmine. Please find the example in the following comment.

Comment: Source code to test:
`function TestSourceCode() {
jqXHRObject = $.getJSON(url, jsonData,function (data) {
// 1st callback
//… some other statement
}).success(function (data) { // line# 1
// 2nd callback
//… some other statement
anotherChildFunction();
});
};

function anotherChildFunction (){
//… some other statement
jqXHRObject.success(function{
// 3rd callback
//… some other statement
});
}`

Jasmine Test Spec

`code`it ("My Test Case",function(){
var jsonData = <data>;
spyOn($, "ajax").andReturn({success:function(c){c(jsonData)}});
TestSourceCode ();
});`

Comment: I know source code look little weird. But I can’t change it now.
From my Jasmine Test Spec, I am able to call 2nd callback function as you suggested. But I am not sure how to call this 3rd callback from my test spec. I am trying in several ways and every time I am getting jqXHRObject.success is not a function. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?