# Jasmine, spyOn, getJSON and fail

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to learn the Jasmine **spyOn** function. I get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'fail'** when using **spyOn** to test a function that calls **jQuery.getJSON**.

Here is the function I want to test:

```
getJsonServerNine: function () {
    'use strict';

    $.getJSON(queryServer.url, function(simpleJson) {
        parseResponse(simpleJson);                
    }).fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error.statusText);
    });

}
```

Here is my test:

```
it("tests getJSON call", function() {
    spyOn($, 'getJSON').and.callFake(function (url, success) {
        success({
            "nine": 9
        });
    });
    queryServer.getJsonServerNine();
    expect(queryServer.queryResult).toBe(9);
});
```

If I remove the **fail** callback from **getJsonServerNine()** then my code works. If I call **jquery.ajax()** instead of **getJSON** then I can find a way to get it to work. How can can I get it to work with a call to **$.getJSON**?

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17575829/253576) to a similar question and it is very nice but does not closely match my case, does not work for me, and uses outdated Jasmine syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object returned by $.getJSON should have a fail() method. In your implementation it returns undefined.

The fake function should return an object like so:

```
// Source
var queryServer = {
    getJsonServerNine: function () {
        'use strict';

        $.getJSON(queryServer.url, function (simpleJson) {
            // parseResponse(simpleJson);
            console.log(simpleJson)
            queryServer.queryResult = simpleJson[Object.keys(simpleJson)[0]];
        }).fail(function (error) {
            console.log(error.statusText);
        });

    }
}

// Test
describe('foo', function () {
    it("tests getJSON call", function () {
        spyOn($, 'getJSON').and.callFake(function (url, success) {
            success({
                "nine": 9
            });
            return {
                fail: function() {}
            }
        });
        queryServer.getJsonServerNine();
        expect(queryServer.queryResult).toBe(9);
    });
});
```

See JS fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/32e17uje/